# Neural Network learns worse on a larger amount of data

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network designed to play a game of snake only from looking at the current state of the game map. It is competing against 3 other snakes on the map. The network trains by watching an "expert snake" play the game and aims to make the same decisions it would at each time step (decisions are: turn left, turn right or proceed straight). When training over 200000 imaged with a batch size of 500 and a dropout rate of 0.5 (50%) the network learns to around an 80% accuracy on the validation data, ranging from 75% to 83%. However when I train over a larger data set of 2 million images (with no change in any other hyper-parameters) the network fails to learn passed 38% which is only slightly better than if it were making random moves. I found the following post: https://www.quora.com/Intuitively-how-does-batch-size-impact-a-convolutional-network-training which lead me to believe that my data was now too noisy and that increasing the batch size would fix my problem. Thus the most recent training session I ran used 2 million images with a batch size of 1000 and drop out rate of 0.75. This resulted in a repeated validation accuracy of 38% again (test accuracy of about 37%). The fact that these adjustments had no affect is worrying. I have changed the learning rate in isolated test which also did not help the test accuracy. Has anyone faced a similar problem? This is very confusing to me as I was under the impression that more training data is almost always a good thing. With all training sessions I run, different images are chosen at random from my set of all images and thus if the network can learn a random subset of the data I would imagine it could learn a larger subset of the data. Thanks in advance for any assistance. To summarize my questions is: what are the possible causes of such a problem and which hyper-parameters would be more influential in causing this type of behaviour?

Comment: but whats the question?

Comment: what does your network look like? what activation function? are you using pooling? I wouldn't for this + 0.75 dropout is very high.

Comment: My network:
input 52x52x1 -> conv with 5x5 window 32 features -> maxpool 2x2 -> conv 4x4 window 64 features -> maxpool 2x2 -> fully connected layer of size 4096 with dropout=0.5 (also tried 0.75) -> output layer of size 3.
 Activation function is relu.
I will try to remove pooling and see what happens, but what would be the reason for not using it? Also does anything else seem weird with the network?
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having above was caused by a bias in my data. The master snake chose to proceed straight more often than it chose to turn left or right combined. Thus our model learnt to only go straight.

In the small data set this would look like it was learning to play the game where in fact it was learning to choose the bias. Thus a larger data set exposed how poorly the model really was learning. Thus it was only correct when straight was the correct answer (just over a third of the time on the large set)

I hope this helps anyone experiencing similar strange behaviour while training their model. Check your data for biases or  counter-productive behaviours.

Our solution was to even out the training data and train the model on an equal amount of left, right and straight positions.